# Export SPSS output in a meaningful format (e.g. csv, tab)?

Tags: excel, csv, export, output, spss

I have some output from SPSS that I've exported as a .txt file (but also as various Excel formats). Below is a snippet from that file. I need the observed and expected percentages for correlation, and this will happen for hundreds of these outputs (many different log linear models). Currently it is formatted with spaces as text, and as Excel it has the whole row in a single cell. I am trying to avoid having to write code to decipher this, as that will also be fraught given the overall size of the outputs, the location of spaces in them etc.

Does anyone have any ideas?

One clear solution is to use a different package, however the ability to specify polynomial contrasts and have the weights calculated for me in the SPSS LOGLINEAR syntax cannot be achieved as easily elsewhere (i.e. it might be possible but it is beyond my skills).

```
 Observed, Expected Frequencies and Residuals

       Factor          Code              OBS. count & PCT.   EXP. count & PCT.      Residual   Std. Resid.   Adj. Resid.


  deg_code        0
   res_code        100
    edge_cod        2.520                    13.00 (  .29)      112.75 ( 2.56)      -99.7500       -9.3941       -9.8118
    edge_cod        0.630                    40.00 (  .91)      112.75 ( 2.56)      -72.7500       -6.8513       -7.1560
    edge_cod        0.315                   130.00 ( 2.95)      112.75 ( 2.56)       17.2500        1.6245        1.6968
    edge_cod        0.105                   194.00 ( 4.40)      112.75 ( 2.56)       81.2500        7.6518        7.9921
   res_code        85
    edge_cod        2.520                    21.00 (  .48)      112.75 ( 2.56)      -91.7500       -8.6407       -9.0249
    edge_cod        0.630                    60.00 ( 1.36)      112.75 ( 2.56)      -52.7500       -4.9678       -5.1887
    edge_cod        0.315                   136.00 ( 3.08)      112.75 ( 2.56)       23.2500        2.1896        2.2870
    edge_cod        0.105                   194.00 ( 4.40)      112.75 ( 2.56)       81.2500        7.6518        7.9921
   res_code        70
    edge_cod        2.520                    70.00 ( 1.59)      112.75 ( 2.56)      -42.7500       -4.0260       -4.2051
    edge_cod        0.630                   117.00 ( 2.65)      112.75 ( 2.56)        4.2500         .4002         .4180
    edge_cod        0.315                   164.00 ( 3.72)      112.75 ( 2.56)       51.2500        4.8265        5.0412
    edge_cod        0.105                   214.00 ( 4.85)      112.75 ( 2.56)      101.2500        9.5354        9.9594

  deg_code        8
   res_code        100
    edge_cod        2.520                    17.00 (  .39)      120.08 ( 2.72)     -103.0833       -9.4069       -9.8252
    edge_cod        0.630                    56.00 ( 1.27)      120.08 ( 2.72)      -64.0833       -5.8480       -6.1080
    edge_cod        0.315                   138.00 ( 3.13)      120.08 ( 2.72)       17.9167        1.6350        1.7077
    edge_cod        0.105                   195.00 ( 4.42)      120.08 ( 2.72)       74.9167        6.8366        7.1405
   res_code        85
    edge_cod        2.520                    27.00 (  .61)      120.08 ( 2.72)      -93.0833       -8.4944       -8.8721
    edge_cod        0.630                    72.00 ( 1.63)      120.08 ( 2.72)      -48.0833       -4.3879       -4.5830
    edge_cod        0.315                   146.00 ( 3.31)      120.08 ( 2.72)       25.9167        2.3650        2.4702
    edge_cod        0.105                   200.00 ( 4.54)      120.08 ( 2.72)       79.9167        7.2928        7.6171
   res_code        70
    edge_cod        2.520                    82.00 ( 1.86)      120.08 ( 2.72)      -38.0833       -3.4753       -3.6298
    edge_cod        0.630                   119.00 ( 2.70)      120.08 ( 2.72)       -1.0833        -.0989        -.1033
    edge_cod        0.315                   172.00 ( 3.90)      120.08 ( 2.72)       51.9167        4.7377        4.9483
    edge_cod        0.105                   217.00 ( 4.92)      120.08 ( 2.72)       96.9167        8.8442        9.2374

  deg_code        16
   res_code        100
    edge_cod        2.520                    39.00 (  .88)      134.67 ( 3.05)      -95.6667       -8.2439       -8.6104
    edge_cod        0.630                    67.00 ( 1.52)      134.67 ( 3.05)      -67.6667       -5.8310       -6.0903
    edge_cod        0.315                   132.00 ( 2.99)      134.67 ( 3.05)       -2.6667        -.2298        -.2400
    edge_cod        0.105                   211.00 ( 4.78)      134.67 ( 3.05)       76.3333        6.5779        6.8703
   res_code        85
    edge_cod        2.520                    48.00 ( 1.09)      134.67 ( 3.05)      -86.6667       -7.4683       -7.8004
    edge_cod        0.630                    87.00 ( 1.97)      134.67 ( 3.05)      -47.6667       -4.1076       -4.2902
    edge_cod        0.315                   161.00 ( 3.65)      134.67 ( 3.05)       26.3333        2.2692        2.3701
    edge_cod        0.105                   212.00 ( 4.81)      134.67 ( 3.05)       77.3333        6.6640        6.9603
   res_code        70
    edge_cod        2.520                    92.00 ( 2.09)      134.67 ( 3.05)      -42.6667       -3.6767       -3.8402
    edge_cod        0.630                   151.00 ( 3.42)      134.67 ( 3.05)       16.3333        1.4075        1.4701
    edge_cod        0.315                   195.00 ( 4.42)      134.67 ( 3.05)       60.3333        5.1991        5.4303
    edge_cod        0.105                   221.00 ( 5.01)      134.67 ( 3.05)       86.3333        7.4396        7.7704
```

Comment: @pnuts That is a sufficient solution, thanks for the tip. I'm not sure how to make your comment an answer though?

Comment: @pnuts perhaps it is more suited to stackexchange

Comment: I have played a bit with the SPSS Python module and found a way to save the text output as a .cvs file with a semicolon (or something similar) as delimiter. However to provide a proper solution, I need to know how your SPSS Viewer File looks like. Does it contain a series of Log Linear Outputs? And how do you like the csv. file(s)? One file for every loglinear result or one file for the whole viewer output?

Comment: @mirirai output can be any format as long as the cells contain the values, and not weird extra bits, like single brackets, and climb bans spread over several cells (this happened die to space delimiting).  The viewer file contains many  outputs that all come out as one clickable chunk of info. Each contains a full analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once in Excel you can use Text to Columns with space as the delimiter to parse the single cells into multiple cells. Having done so you might choose to save the result as character separated values, should you prefer the .csv format.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, and written up a more comprehensive list of instructions for others coming here with less knowledge of Excel. Thanks again.

Comment: I'd need to wait two days, and besides, your's was the answer, mine is simply an elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

For those here from Google, @pnuts gave me a simple answer that I had overlooked; "Text to Columns" in Excel.

For those that aren't aware of it (as I was not), the process to conver SPSS data output as Excel into a useable (i.e. values in cells) format is as follows:
Export your data output from SPSS by right clicking and selecting export, chose an excel format and a destination. Alternatively you can use this syntax (fill in the filepath):

```
   *Export Output to Excel.
  OUTPUT EXPORT
  /CONTENTS  EXPORT=ALL  LAYERS=PRINTSETTING  MODELVIEWS=PRINTSETTING
  /XLS  DOCUMENTFILE='C:\FILEPATHHERE'
     OPERATION=CREATEFILE
     LOCATION=LASTCOLUMN  NOTESCAPTIONS=YES.
```

Once you have your file, you'll notice all your data/output is in column 1.

1. Select the column of data
2. Click Data > Text to Columns in the ribbon
3. Select "delimited" > next
4. Make sure that "text", and "treat consecutive delimiters as one" are all that is checked > next
5. And finally you can adjust the data type or simply finish.

This is a simple process I know, but I have leaned over the years that people have different levels of knowledge about such things, and while frequent visitors to Stackoverflow might be al over this, the odd Googler might not be.

Edit*
An alternative solution I am currently using (for only a few outputs at a time) is to right click 'copy special' in SPSS, as text, then paste special in excel, and keep source formatting. This might be made into a macro by someone smarter than I!

-Alex

Answer (score 1):

Have you cosidered using GENLOG instead of the very old LOGLINEAR procedure, which only produces plain text output?  GENLOG (Analyze>Loglinear>General) produces regular pivot table output as well as residual and predicted value variables, so its output could be exported directly to Excel using Output Export or OMS with no fussing around on the Excel

Comment: I needed it because of the ability to specify polynomial weights, does GENLOG slow for this? Also my uni installation probably didn't have it, it's the studestudent 2011 version.

Comment: You can read a detailed comparison of the LOGLINEAR and GENLOG approaches in the Command Syntax Reference accessible from the Help menu.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with JKP, using the newer GENLOG procedure is probably a better way. However, in some cases you might want to transform a text output into a csv file. Therefore I like to share this solution.

In this solution I grep the viewer output with help of the SpssClient Python class and then make use of some native [python](/questions/tagged/python) functions to manipulate the text output and save it as csv files.

As example data I use 'demo.sav' from the SPSS example files.

```
**** create some sample output ****.

GET FILE='/opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/22/Samples/English/demo.sav'.

LOGLINEAR inccat (1,4) jobsat (1,5)
   /DESIGN inccat.

LOGLINEAR inccat (1,4) ownpc (0,1)
   /DESIGN inccat.

**** transform output to csv files ****

BEGIN PROGRAM.
import csv
import re
import os
import SpssClient

# define directory where the csv files will be stored
os.chdir("/your/path/to/directory/")

# define csv file basename
basename = 'loglin'

# define delimeter for csv files
delim = ';'


SpssClient.StartClient()

OutputDoc = SpssClient.GetDesignatedOutputDoc()
OutputItems = OutputDoc.GetOutputItems()

# create list wich contains the several text outputs 
# of the LogLinear procedures
TextItems = []

for index in range(OutputItems.Size()):
   OutputItem = OutputItems.GetItemAt(index)
   if (OutputItem.GetType() == SpssClient.OutputItemType.TEXT 
   and OutputItem.GetProcedureName() == 'Loglinear'):
      TextItem = OutputItem.GetSpecificType()
      TextItems.append(TextItem.GetTextContents())

SpssClient.StopClient()

# some fine tuning, so that actual values get into
# one table cell, without brackets and stuff like that
def stringadj (astring):
   astring = re.sub(r' +\( *', delim, astring) # replace left bracket by delimeter
   astring = re.sub(r'\)', '', astring) # remove right bracket
   astring = re.sub(r' & ', delim, astring) # replace '&' by delimeter
   astring = re.sub(r'= ?', '=' + delim, astring) # replace '=' by delimeter
   astring = re.sub(delim + delim, delim, astring) # replace double delimeter by single delimeter
   return astring

# define cvs style
csv.register_dialect('loglinstyle', delimiter=delim)

# split output strings into several lines
# do necessary text adjustments
# and store each output in a seperate (enumerated) csv file
for position, item in enumerate(TextItems):
   lltable = [re.sub(r' ( )+', delim, line.lstrip().rstrip()) for line in item.split("\n")]

   lltable = [stringadj(line) for line in lltable]

   filename = basename + str(position+1) + '.csv'

   with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
      writer = csv.writer(f, 'loglinstyle')
      writer.writerows(csv.reader(lltable, 'loglinstyle'))

END PROGRAM.
```